# Angular-cli : How to ignore class names from being minified

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, bundling-and-minification

For an application we need to keep the classname not minified because we use

```
var className = myObject.constructor.name;
export class myObject{ ... }
```

when we run

ng build -- pro

the class name gets minified in a random name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular cli uses webpack and uglify internally. One solution would be changing the options in uglify by exporting the webpack configuration. You can see the webpack files by running ng eject, and ng eject --prod

```
new UglifyJsPlugin({
      "mangle": false,
      "compress": {
        "screw_ie8": true,
        "warnings": false
      },
      "sourceMap": false
    }),
```

Mangle = false will preserve class names. The lack of options for webpack in angular cli is one big discussion atm.

You can alse set exclusions like this:

```
mangle: {
    except: ['foozah']
  }
```

Note: after ejecting you can remove ejected true from angular-cli.json to do it again or serve/build normally.

```
"project": {
    "name": "test",
    "ejected": true //remove
  },
```

Comment: After editing to build, use 'npm start' , or 'npm run build'.

Comment: Just a point to remember, once we use `ng eject` then we not able to use angular-cli goodies with it.

Comment: *ng eject* is not working in latest version of angular-cli, is there any other approach by which we can configure mangle in prod build ?

Answer (score 16):

Angular cli builder supports `NG_BUILD_MANGLE`, `NG_BUILD_MINIFY`, `NG_BUILD_BEAUTIFY` node environment params (checked in version 8).

You can set them when running npm script in following way:
`env NG_BUILD_MANGLE=false NG_BUILD_MINIFY=false NG_BUILD_BEAUTIFY=true ng build --prod`

This will result in unminified output, yet tree shaking and other optimizations will still be applied (compared to just turning off optimization).

Comment: How do i set this env can you explain in detail

Comment: `NG_BUILD_MANGLE = false` is still renaming class name

Comment: For other people that might have the same problem: `.angular` folder caches the last build, and if you don't change your code between builds it will reuse the last build and won't notice the change in flag `NG_BUILD_MANGLE`. So the solution is to either make change in code or delete `.angular` folder in between builds without changes.

Answer (score 6):

For Angular 9-12, some of the other answers don't work anymore.

Similar to [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63152647/2184266), we didn't want to worry about maintaining modified versions of `@angular-devkit/build-angular`, so I instead used `ngx-build-plus` as our builder in order to introduce a simple plugin to the build process that overrides the Terser config. This works for Angular 9-11.

I created a new file named `build-plugin.js`:

```
exports.default = {
  pre: function () {
  },
  config: function (cfg) {
    // Override Angular's internal configuration of Terser to preserve class names.
    // This won't work if you build multiple (differential) client bundles, so make sure you only target es5 builds in tsconfig.json.
    // See https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/144#issuecomment-576424615
    cfg.optimization.minimizer.forEach(function (it) {
      if (it.constructor.name === 'TerserPlugin') {
        it.options.terserOptions["keep_fnames"] = true;
        it.options.terserOptions["keep_classnames"] = true;
      }
    });
    return cfg;
  },
  post: function () {
  }
};
```

Then updated the project's `angular.json`:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "my-project": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",
          "options": {
            "plugin": "~build-plugin.js",
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

In Angular 12, they've changed the code optimizer [from `TerserPlugin` to `JavaScriptOptimizerPlugin`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/12.2.x/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/webpack/configs/common.ts#L375) for most projects. So just update `build-plugin.js` to include an override for it as well:

```
if (it.constructor.name === 'TerserPlugin') {
    it.options.terserOptions["keep_fnames"] = true;
    it.options.terserOptions["keep_classnames"] = true;
} else if (it.constructor.name === 'JavaScriptOptimizerPlugin') {
    it.options.keepNames = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

adding to yantrab's answer for angular 8.2+ using [angular-builders](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders)

in angular.json

builder: `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser`

options:

```
    "customWebpackConfig": {
      "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
      "mergeStrategies": {
        "externals": "replace"
      }
    },
```

in extra-webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = config => {
  config.optimization.minimizer.filter (({constructor: {name}}) => name === 'TerserPlugin')
  .forEach (terser => {
    terser.options.terserOptions.keep_classnames = true;
  });

  return config;
};
```

then either target es5 or es2015 with differential loading disabled per the browserslist discussed here: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/144#issuecomment-568890065

Answer (score 2):

angular 8 using terser.

this is my config for [angular builder](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) :

```
module.exports = cfg => {
    const options = cfg.optimization.minimizer[cfg.optimization.minimizer.length - 1].options.terserOptions;
    options.keep_classnames = true;
    return cfg;
};
```

and change terget to es6

Comment: Thanks for solution but I am facing one issue is that - after following all the steps which you mention but now I am facing one problem like a class name append before like - 
consider a class is AbLogin then after production build class name became ab_login_AbLogin

Comment: In my case, the terser plugin is not necessarily the right one

Comment: this was working for us in angular 8 up to 8.1. it seems in angular 8.2 cli or greater (including angular 9+), the cli will ignore terserOptions if differential loading is enabled. it took me quite a while to figure that out. there is also a better way to set the terserOptions as the above code only modifies one minimizer when in reality there are multiple. see this issue for the solution: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/144

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to avoid mangling specific symbols by doing the following:

- Use the `NG_BUILD_MANGLE=false $NG build --prod ...` approach to tell angular to avoid doing any mangling of names.
- Use [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus) which merges a partial webpack config with the one used by angular. Use the terser plugin to perform mangling, but make sure to pass it the reserved list of names you don't want to be mangled.

```
ng add ngx-build-plus
```

An example of the sort of webpack.partial.js you could use is:

```js
const terser = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new terser.TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          compress: false,
          mangle: {
            reserved: [
              "MyClassName1", ...
            ]
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

(n.b. make sure you've run `npm install --save-dev webpack` as well!)

And then amend your build command so it's of this form:

```
NG_BUILD_MANGLE=false ng build --prod ... --extra-webpack-config webpack.partial.js -o
```

These two things combined tell the angular build process to avoid mangling and lets your configured instance of TerserPlugin do the mangling at a later stage whilst respecting the classes you want to remain un-mangled.

Comment: How do i set this NG_BUILD_MANGLE=false.

Comment: `NG_BUILD_MANGLE=false ng build --prod`

Answer (score 0):

The option in mangle:

```
"mangle":{
   "keep_names" : true
}
```

Keeps the class names intact.

Comment: Shoudn't that  be **keep_fnames: true,**

Answer (score 0):

Building off Andres M's answer, you can disable mangling without `ng eject` by directly modifying the Angular file that controls the settings for Webpack: `node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/common.js`

Note that this will be overwritten whenever `@angular-devkit/build-angular` is updated, and is not supported by Angular or NPM (and may kill your cat/cause a nuclear armageddon, don't say I didn't warn you!)

I disabled mangling entirely by changing `uglifyOptions` to `uglifyOptions: Object.assign(uglifyOptions, {mangle: false})`.

For reference, here's the relevant portion from my modified `common.js` file

```
...
new UglifyJSPlugin({
  sourceMap: buildOptions.sourceMap,
  parallel: true,
  cache: true,
  uglifyOptions: Object.assign(uglifyOptions, {"mangle": false})
}),
...
```