# Angular / Typescript class.name does not work in production build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular5

Using Angular 5. Facing a weird issue with class.name property. We have the following function in typescript:

```
export class ApiService
{
  public list<T>(c: new(values: Object)=> T)
  {
    var cname = c.name;
    ....
  }
}
```

Now, if I use this function in dev build of Angular (ng-build) like the following:

```
export class Employee()
{
    public id:string;
    public name: string;

    constructor(values: Object = {}) {          
       Object.assign(this, values);          
    }
}
```

And in code somewhere:

```
var list = api.list(Employee);
```

The above works, and in the list function I get cname = 'Employee'

However, if we build this solution using ng build --env=prod, the code fails and we get cname = undefined.

Why is this happening, and how to resolve it ? Shouldn't something that compiles and works in dev build, work in production ?

Comment: Anyway I wouldn't rely on function/class name as it likely to change after minification.

Comment: Why you used 'new' keyword for this generic?

Comment: Well, that was the syntax we saw in documentation to get the generic working, were getting errors otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely running into an issue with minification, which only occurs during a `prod` build.  Minification will rename your classes in order achieve the smallest output file size.

See this question and answer for a related discussion: [Angular-cli : How to ignore class names from being minified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44160894/1063392)

As the answer above mentions, in order to configure this option, you will need `ng eject` your app, which will allow you customize UglifyJS options (the library responsible for minification), but this will also prevent you from using some of the nice features of the Angular CLI (like `ng build` and `ng serve`).

See this GitHub comment for a description of `ng eject`: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6302#issuecomment-301220770

Comment: Thank you for that. We did realize it was a mistake to use the name property for classes due to clear minification issues. We used static variable instead which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with production code where 'constructor.name' was returning an empty string. My solution was to decorate the classes I needed where the decorator would reassign 'name' at run time with an arbitrary class-name or one passed thru as a parameter: here is the decorator:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
var __global__ClassName__id__ = 0;
export function ClassName(useThisName: string = null) {
    return function (target: any) {
       if (target.name.length === 0 || useThisName !== null) {
            Object.defineProperty(target, "name", {
                value: useThisName !== null ? useThisName : `__ClassName__${++__global__ClassName__id__}`,
                enumerable: false,
                writable: false,
                configurable: true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and code would look like this:

```
// generate a dynamic class name
@Decorator.ClassName()
export class PopupMessage{ }

// uses the argument as class name
@Decorator.ClassName("PopupMessage")
export class PopupMessage{ }

// and code will work as usual
var something = new Message.PopupMessage(1);
var samething = (<any>something).constructor.name == Message.PopupMessage.name;
```