# svg.js + Angular 7.3: Build in production mode get 'not a constructor'

Tags: angular, svg.js

In **development mode** this code works perfectly:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import SVG from "@svgdotjs/svg.js/src/svg"   //v 3.0.12

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'svgjs30';
  draw: any

  ngOnInit() {
    this.draw = SVG().addTo('#canvas').viewbox(0, 0, 300, 140)
    var text = this.draw.text('ABCDE')

  }
}
```

but in **production mode** (after ng b --prod) I get

```
main.b6499f06315e700352a1.js:1 ERROR TypeError: du[e] is not a constructor
    at mu (main.b6499f06315e700352a1.js:1)
    at yu (main.b6499f06315e700352a1.js:1)
    at Ul.addTo (main.b6499f06315e700352a1.js:1)
    at t.ngOnInit (main.b6499f06315e700352a1.js:1)
    at main.b6499f06315e700352a1.js:1
    at main.b6499f06315e700352a1.js:1
    at Yo (main.b6499f06315e700352a1.js:1)
    at _s (main.b6499f06315e700352a1.js:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives (main.b6499f06315e700352a1.js:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives (main.b6499f06315e700352a1.js:1)
```

*[trata tata ta]*

Comment: Try the current master and see if it fixes the issue for you

Comment: @Fuzzyma :),  All what I use is preety fresh. 14-18 day old. Version 3.0.12

Comment: I know how old it is. I released it. And therefore I ask you to try the current master :P

Comment: :) With master is OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a summary of the issues posted on the svg.js GitHub page:**

At the time of writing this, the npm package `@svgdotjs/svg.js v0.3.12` has code that relies on calling `Function.name`. There is a [fix for this issue](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/967) on the current master branch, but it has not been published to NPM yet (more info here: https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/1005).

**Solutions:**

As a work-around (until the next version is published), you can use similar rules in your build process to [the rules used by svg.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/blob/master/.config/rollup.config.js#L42) when it is built. **Specifically, you will need to tell your minifier to not mangle a specific [list of function names](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/blob/a1276f1c20323665d0f6dda8bf7d7e4ba525d1ce/.config/rollup.config.js#L42).** I am not sure how it would be done in Angular 7, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160894/angular-cli-how-to-ignore-class-names-from-being-minified) might be helpful place to start (Angular 5).

Alternatively (and I don't particularly recommend this) you can download the latest master branch, run the build command, and then copy the built code into your source directory and use it directly instead of using the NPM package.