# Avoid Mangle Class Name in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, uglifyjs

I have a Single Page Application in Angular 8. In this application, I use in typescript class the constructor name to perform some Operations. All is working fine in developpement.

```
class User {
  GetClassName() {
     return this.constructor.name;
  } 
  // returns "User"
}
```

However when I build in production mode :

`npm run ng build -- --configuration=prod`

Angular perform a lot of optimization including Uglify Class Name

```
class User {
  GetClassName() {
     return this.constructor.name;
  }
  // returns "t"
}
```

So my constructor name is Now t and not user.
How to configure Angular Build to avoid Uglify some class name or all class name ?

It seems that's when can replace mangle option but i wouldn't do that in my nodemodule but prefer use a custom config file given on build.

Did someone succesfully do that ?

Thanks for all

Comment: Please improve the question. It can be misleading and inaccurate of what you are looking for. Avoid downvotes and increase the chance of the right answer by giving a complete explanation of what you are looking to accomplish, and if possible, add code to clarify.

Comment: I do not more needed this kind of features. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

from: [Angular-cli : How to ignore class names from being minified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160894/angular-cli-how-to-ignore-class-names-from-being-minified)

Angular cli builder supports NG_BUILD_MANGLE, NG_BUILD_MINIFY, NG_BUILD_BEAUTIFY node environment params (checked in version 8).

You can set them when running npm script in following way: env NG_BUILD_MANGLE=false NG_BUILD_MINIFY=false NG_BUILD_BEAUTIFY=true ng build --prod

This will result in unminified output, yet tree shaking and other optimizations will still be applied (compared to just turning off optimization).

Answer (score -1):

@rdethurens could you add any example about what you are looking for? I think you could add a custom class in the html tag you want change adding ngClass.

For example:

```
<div [ngClass]="myClass">...</div>
```

Comment: Thnaks for your answer, I edit my first post to add example !